# Using Powershell to strip a row from a CSV that contains a specific word?

Tags: powershell, csv

Here are some sample rows from my CSV file.

```
"ComputerName","Name","Publisher","InstallDate","EstimatedSize","Version","Wow6432Node"
"pcnumber1","Service Pack 1 for Microsoft Office 2013 (KB2850036) 32-Bit Edition","Microsoft P",,"0",,"True"
"pcnumber1","CCleaner","Piriform",,"0","5.01",
```

The original script pulls a large amount of information about installed software from a specified computer and outputs it into a CSV format. I want to take that CSV file and remove all rows that have "Microsoft P" in them. I have found how to remove specific words from a string, how to find and replace, etc. I am having a hard time finding this specific function though.

Comment: `FINDSTR /V "Microsoft P" SomeFile.CSV > NewFile.CSV`

Comment: That feels painfully simple and I don't know how I missed it. However, it seems if I do that, it also removes all rows with just the word "Microsoft" in them as well.

Comment: "Microsoft P" can only be found in the publisher column?

Comment: Correct! I will specify that.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can import, select all elements not containing "Microsoft P" using Where-Object, and export:

```
Import-Csv test.csv | where {$_.Publisher -ne "Microsoft P"} | Export-Csv New.csv -notypeinfo
```

Comment: This seems like the "PowerShell" way to go.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `FINDSTR` as Mark Setchell suggests.  Just indicate that it is a literal search string with `/C`.

```
FINDSTR /V /C:"Microsoft P" SomeFile.CSV > NewFile.CSV
```

Comment: Thank you for the correction - I was not in front of a Windows box to test it and that is why I didn't put it as an answer. Have my vote.

Answer (score 2):

Or if you want a PowerShell solution you can ignore the fact that it's a CSV and just treat it like a text file. Then you could:

```
Get-Content C:\Path\To\File.csv | Where{$_ -notmatch "Microsoft P"} | Out-File C:\Path\To\NewFile.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do multiple strings using

```
FINDSTR /V /C:"Microsoft P" /C:"Linux R" /C:"Whatever W" SomeFile.CSV > NewFile.CSV
```